# App.ScreenWidth with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Referencing code found at...[Highlight a Route on a Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/polyline/)

They show...

```
var customMap = new CustomMap
{
    WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth
};
```

`App.ScreenWidth` isn't available any longer.  Has it been replaced with `Application.Current.MainPage.Width`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current screen width in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891654/get-current-screen-width-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most simplest and accurate way to get device height & width in PCL:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ABC
{
    public class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        private double _width;
        private double _height;

        public MyPage()
        {
            Content = new Label 
            {
                WidthRequest = _width,
                Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            };
        }

        protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
        {
            base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
            _width = width;
            _height = height;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In that demo, `App.ScreenWidth` and `App.ScreenHeight` are static variables defined in the [`App`](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/blob/0fb090956852b1a24d36b34de425225ad4ef973d/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/Maps/MapOverlay/Circle/MapOverlay/App.cs) class and assigned in the `native` projects:

iOS app project:

```
App.ScreenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
App.ScreenHeight = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height
```

Android app project:

```
App.ScreenWidth = (width - 0.5f) / density;
App.ScreenHeight = (height - 0.5f) / density;
```

Ref: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/search?p=2&q=ScreenWidth&utf8=✓

Answer (score 0):

I believe the alternative, the OP suggested in the question, is the correct answer.
[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38891835/592651)

Update: One problem with this solution is that it will return -1 when MainPage did not appear yet.  In this case, @SushiHangover solution is better.