# Is it possible to differentiate between a 5 inch and 7inch ( 7 inch and 10 inch )device in Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using idioms we are able to distinguish between a tablet and phone but will it be possible to differentiate between a 5 inch and 7-inch device or say 7 inch and 10-inch devices. Here the scenario is that I need to define the no of columns in the forms UI based on the size, ie in 5 inch device I would need to have 3 columns and in 7-inch device 4 columns and in 10-inch devices say column equals 5 (All the columns counts apply for portrait and in landscape it increases).
Could anyone elaborate on how to handle the situation, portrait, and landscape?

Comment: there isn't a built in helper for this, but you can check the width and height of the UI and derive your answer from that

Comment: @Jason How to check the device width and height in Xamarin forms?
Are you suggesting OnSizeAllocated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891654/get-current-screen-width-in-xamarin-forms