# get width and height of mobile using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin.forms. I want to get height,width and resolution of my mobile programmatically in xamarin.forms. Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current screen width in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891654/get-current-screen-width-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: hi jason, 
Thanks for the reply. But i am getting -1 as width using 
string wid = Application.Current.MainPage.Width.ToString();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms) NuGet pakage was released and there is a useful class `DeviceDisplay` in there that should handle this task for you.

The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display).

Usage example:

```
// Get Metrics
var metrics = DeviceDisplay.ScreenMetrics;

// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = metrics.Orientation;

// Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
var rotation = metrics.Rotation;

// Width (in pixels)
var width = metrics.Width;

// Height (in pixels)
var height = metrics.Height;

// Screen density
var density = metrics.Density;
```

Comment: when i add "using Xamarin.Essentials;", it shows error. any suggestions...

Comment: Without knowing your error it will be hard to help. Wild shot maybe you are not on .NET Standard? Check the documentation links that I provided in my answer, there is a very nice getting started section in the official docs.

Comment: This seems to have changed to `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height` etc