# Fill Screen with Grid of Fixed Size Cells

Tags: xamarin.forms, layout, cell, launcher, measure

I am trying to implement a launcher screen for my Xamarin.Forms app.  As such it contains several `Grid`s of icon buttons, each grid within a `CarouselView` pane.  The icon button cells will be of a fixed size.

Typically, I will size a grid with a known number of rows and columns, and the cell size is calculated accordingly.  Here I need to go the opposite direction, from a known cell size to a calculated number of rows and columns.  The more I look at it, the more it seems I may end up needing to [Create a Custom Layout in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom), where I see things like using [VisualElement.Measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.measure) to determine parent element sizes from children elements.

Before I chase that option down though, does anyone know if/how I can get the number of fixed-size cells a `Grid` can contain before it is rendered?

Comment: How big is this Grid going to be?  Multiple CarouselView on a page sounds like a performance hog.  Regardless, using the screen dimensions to calculate the number of cells that will fit on the page seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: One `CarouselView`, multiple `Grid`s.  Both take up the whole screen.  Seems straightforward, but I'm bad at UI design.

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling around, I think I have settled on something of a workable design.  Ended up actually using a `CollectionView` instead of a `Grid`:

```
<CarouselView
    ItemsSource="{Binding LauncherPanes}"
    Loop="False">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:LauncherPaneViewModel">
            <CollectionView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Span="4" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:LauncherIconViewModel">
                        <controls:LauncherIconView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

This still requires that I don't popuplate each pane of the carousel with more icons than the pane can hold, though technically even if I did that the `CollectionView` would just scroll vertically within the pane.

Comment: I think this is an easier solution than populating a grid. [Screen Dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50450173/199364) may be helpful in calculating how many items.